# TextBox TranslateTransform Animation

Tags: wpf, animation, text, textbox

I have a TextBlock In My Application. I want to TranslateTransform Animation each word In My
TextBlock. This would be similar to Text Effect's Exist In PowerPoint.

For example: each word would move 20px to up and then return to last position

Comment: it sounds like this question and answers "Why isn't TextBox.Text in WPF animatable?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603683/why-isnt-textbox-text-in-wpf-animatable

Comment: I think it may be easier to use separate `TextBlock` for every word.

Answer (score 0):

In my research, I Found a sample From Microsoft that I used to see how I can make this Work.

First we define TextEffects For TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock.TextEffects>
                                    <TextEffectCollection>
                                        <TextEffect PositionCount="1" x:Name="TxtEffect">
                                            <TextEffect.Transform>
                                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="Transform" X="0" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
                                            </TextEffect.Transform>
                                        </TextEffect>
                                    </TextEffectCollection>
</TextBlock.TextEffects>
```

Second, we define the Animations:

1) Animation For Increase PositionCount With Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames And Define's
Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames The Number Of Words Exist In Text

2) Animation For TranslateTransform To Move Each Word

Example For Three Words:

```
 <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" From="0" To="20" BeginTime="0:0:0" Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" From="20" To="-20" BeginTime="0:0:0.25" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Transform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y" From="-20" To="0" BeginTime="0:0:0.75" Duration="0:0:0.25" />
                                    </Storyboard>
 </BeginStoryboard>

 <BeginStoryboard Name="TxtEf">
               <Storyboard>
                        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TxtEffect" 
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="PositionStart"
                                                                      Duration="0:0:2.5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>

                                                <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                                                <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame Value="1" KeyTime="0:0:1" />
                                                <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame Value="2" KeyTime="0:0:2" />

                                            </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>

                          </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
               </Storyboard>
```