# Data change in DataContext with animation

Tags: wpf, data-binding, animation, datacontext

i have no idea to solve the problem with follwing code:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="InternalData" XPath="/Workspace">
      <x:XData>
        <Workspace Name="Workspace" xmlns="">
          <Project Name="Project 1"/>
          <Project Name="Project 2"/>
          <Project Name="Project 3"/>
        </Workspace>
      </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource InternalData}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=//Workspace/Project}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>        
    <TextBox Text="{Binding XPath=//Workspace/Project[1]/@Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

As you can see, i can change the Name of the first Project in the Workspace with the TextBox.
By changing the data, i want to start an animation to fade out the old value, change the value and start an animation to fade in the new value (e.g. opacity of "Project 1" from 1 to 0, change data and opacity of "" from 0 to 1)
If possible, i wanted to implement the solution only in XAML. But no idea. Maybe something with DataTrigger and EnterAction and ExitAction or stuff like that?

Kind regards
Shounborugh

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try looking in to WPF storyboards. This is a common practice if you want to start an animation using only XAML. This is the best place to start about storyboards in WPF
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx

This is how you can start the storyboard upon changing the text in the textbox

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,44,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <TextBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>

                        </Storyboard>

                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>

            </TextBox.Triggers>

        </TextBox>
```

Comment: I know the basics of storyboards, but the problem is how to begin a storyboard, when data change. I thought a datatrigger could help me. But i don't know which property i have to set to the datatrigger to trigger a change and start a storyboard with the old value and start a storyboard with the new value. The main problem is to hold the old value.

Comment: Is the code working properly? what i meant is are you able to see the project names "project 1" "project 2" "proeject 3" and so on in the textbox that you have set the text to be binding?

Comment: Thanks for this solution and i see the names in my ListBox. But that not direct this what im looking for ^^. The TextBox should only be an example for me to test. With the solution you posted i dont know how to fade out the old value of the changing content and fading in the new content. For example i change the TextBox.Text-Property which is binded to the first item in DataContext. The old value - "Project 1" and the new value - Project abc". The first storyboard starts fading out (Opacity to 0) "Project 1", change the content and fading in the new value "project abc" (opacity to 1)

Comment: Well there is a catch you wont be able to perform any textbox.text fading this should give http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603683/why-isnt-textbox-text-in-wpf-animatable you a clear picture.. and anything beyond that i am not sure how. But one workaround is use a textblock in the place of textbox.text shld be possible.. and dont forget to mark this as answer if it helps..tks

Comment: Not the TextBox.Text should be animated. The content with the data of a ListBoxItem generated by the ListBox should be animated when the binded DataContext (and the data for the affected ListBoxItems) changed. Maybe i talking to much around the real problem, sry about that (i give my best with my english). Having you maybe an idea now?

Comment: hi i am not sure how to do that but i will c what i can do