# Animate the textbox.text property

Tags: .net, wpf, storyboard

The question below is a bit confusing
[Why isn't TextBox.Text in WPF animatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603683/why-isnt-textbox-text-in-wpf-animatable)
 as i am unable to understand whether if the question is answered as in with a solution / workaround or just explained the technical backdrop of why this cannot happen.

What ever it might be i am having the same situation and would like to know how to animate the textbox text property using the WPF storyboard.

This is a sample code that i have as of now.

```
<Grid>

        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,44,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="">
            <TextBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="textBox1.Text" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                             From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>

                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>

            </TextBox.Triggers>

        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextBox Text="tata" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black">
        <TextBox.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBox.TextChanged">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" To="Transparent" Duration="0:0:2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>                  
                </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: TextBox.Text is a c# string and therefore does not have an opacity property, hence why it can't be animated. Denis has a clever solution here in which he animates the font color the TextBox uses to transparent, effectively achieving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TargetName` should be `textBox1`, not `textBox1.Text`. The `Opacity` property exists on `TextBox`, not on `String` (which is the type of `TextBox.Text`).

Comment: yes Kent understand that so how to apply the opacity for the Text property?

Comment: What you're asking to do doesn't make sense. The `Text` property is a `String`. A `String` has no concept of opacity - it's just a series of characters. Opacity is only relevant to any control extending `UIElement`. If you want to change the opacity of the `TextBlock` within the `TextBox` without affecting the opacity of the other elements comprising the `TextBox`, then you'll need to re-template.

Comment: Oh ok ..but could you please take a look at this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603683/why-isnt-textbox-text-in-wpf-animatable here did they achieve that in the end?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're asking now. You're using a DoubleAnimation and are trying to animate opacity. The linked question is using a StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames and is trying to animate the text property.