# Set TextProperty on Storyboard

Tags: wpf, storyboard, eventtrigger

Sorry if my question is all to trivial, but I can't find the right solution.
I have a Storyboard where a TextProperty should be set to {x:Null}
How I can do this?

This is my code, but it don't work:

```
<Button.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_FilterTextBox" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Button.Triggers>
```

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603683/why-isnt-textbox-text-in-wpf-animatable/2603862#2603862 You can not animate `TextBox.Text` property, so you should do this by using another way, not `Storyboard`.

Comment: Yes, you´r right. I can´t. So I go an another strange way. But if it is the solution... Cheers!

Comment: I have solved this problem with a behavior class. The visual parent control, has a behavior now, that make the needed application moves

Comment: You can add this as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the solution-source are the proprietary of my entrepreneur, so I can (for legal reasons) they do not introduce. Sorry!